# Retrieve the formated URL from open_id form

Tags: php, openid, janrain

I just added OpenID to my website using the PHP janrain libraries, and I got everything working but I have a question about how to do something.

After receiving the openid_url from the user, I pass it to the openid lib, which then processes the url and gets it ready to send to the OP.  How can I retrieve that URL?

Why I ask is because my script currently sees http://mysite.com and mysite.com as different URLs.  I know the library normalizes the URL, I just don't know how to extract it.

I hope I made sense, and thank you for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the final URL you want to use for tracking purposes back with a `Auth_OpenID_SuccessResponse` object, in the `claimed_id` attribute.  (The `getDisplayIdentifier()` method outputs a version more intended for human consumption, which may or may not be different.)

Comment: Awesome, this information helped me a lot.

For anybody else who wants more details:
=== AFTER ===
if ($response->status == Auth_OpenID_SUCCESS)
{

== INSERT THIS ==
$openid = $response->getDisplayIdentifier();

and then $openid is the corrected url.  Tested to work great so far.

Thanks Chaos!